# Is it possible to redirect a url with cookie value?

Tags: java, cookies, http-redirect

Is it possible to redirect a url with cookie value? like:

http://www.test.com/app1/test;JSESSIONID_app1=jklasjfads
Here, The domain is
http://www.test.com/

Application name is,

```
app1
```

page name is,

```
/test
```

Cookie name and value is,

```
JSESSIONID=jhfsdjjkdghJdjklkdjdj
```

Comment: you mean to say if cookie value is `xyz` then you want to redirect to something like `www.test.com/xyz`?

Comment: @RamanSahasi I have edited my post check it

Comment: You might make it clear that you want the cookie to be a matrix parameter in the revised URL.  I'm not an expert, but rewriting the URL might interfere with cacheing.